# How to convert datetime to timestamp Python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, unix-timestamp, seconds

I need to get how many seconds have passed since an element created which is stored as a datetime element in datastore (Google App Engine). I am using a datetime variable. But I could not convert the time difference to seconds.
(Python 2.7)

Here is my aim:

```
def time_difference(datetime_time):
    return int(datetime.now()-datetime_time) #result should be in seconds like 612
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting datetime returns a timedelta. In Python 2.7 timedelta has a total_seconds() method.

```
def time_difference(datetime_time):
    delta = datetime.now() - datetime_time
    return int(delta.total_seconds())
```